# Loop endlessly on lazy-seq

Tags: clojure

Why does the second evaluation with [butlast](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/16ebe679e6a5fd1c7c24df5f9b9b5056bc18d2ec/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L277) loop endlessly in Clojure?

```
user=> (->> (range) butlast lazy-seq (take 0))
()
user=> (->> (range) butlast lazy-seq first) ; ...
```

The equivalent in Haskell can be reasonably lazy-eval'ed.

```
ghci> take 0 . init $ [0..]
[]
ghci> head . init $ [0..]
0
```

**Edit**

[take 0](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/16ebe679e6a5fd1c7c24df5f9b9b5056bc18d2ec/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L2876) is no-op as being pointed out below.

Comment: What would be the second last element of an infinite sequence?

Comment: Infinte sequence has only the lower bound. I think we can't get anything backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the implementation of `butlast`, you can see that it's eager (using `loop` instead of `lazy-seq`). An alternate lazy implementation would do what you want:

```
(defn butlast'
  "Like clojure.core/butlast but lazy."
  [xs]
  (when (seq xs)
    ((fn f [[x & xs]]
       (if (seq xs)
         (lazy-seq (cons x (f xs)))
         ()))
     xs)))
```

Comment: `(->> (range) butlast' first)` is lazy-eval'ed rather `0` than `1`.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does the second evaluation loop endlessly in Clojure?

`butlast` is non-lazy as it enumerates the entire input sequence and builds up a new collection until it exhausts the input.

In both versions `butlast` is eliminating upstream laziness, so I think another relevant question is "why does the first version ever return when `butlast` is involved?": `take 0` is a no-op — it doesn't consume the input sequence when *n* isn't a positive number, so it doesn't matter what you pass it.

Also, I think the equivalent Clojure code to `head . tail $ [0..]` would be:

```
(->> (range) rest first) ;; => 1
```

`butlast` is kinda the opposite of what you'd want.

Comment: Right on it. Corrected from `tail` to `init`.